# Filtering a list of values in Django admin field, based on a previous field value selection

Tags: python, django, admin

In a Django application that I have I'm using these models:

- Agency
- Client
- Profile

A `Client` can have only one `Agency` and an `Agency` can have many `Clients`.

When I'm editing/creating a `Profile` I first select the `Agency`, then I can select multiple `Clients` (and this is ok).

My problem is that in the `Clients` field I see ALL existing `Clients`, while I would want to see only `Clients` related to the selected `Agency`. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: It'll be better if you provide some code that you've written so far.

Answer (score 2):

That app can help, i think (Django application to handle chained model fields) - https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects

link in pypi - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-smart-selects/

Comment: I've tried to use smart-selects, but when I try to edit a Profile I get this error: column agencies_userprofile.clients_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...e"."user_id", "agencies_userprofile"."agency_id", "agencies_...

This is how I used it:

clients = ChainedForeignKey(
        Client, 
        chained_field="agency",
        chained_model_field="agency", 
        show_all=False, 
        auto_choose=True
    )

Comment: as far as I know, syncdb doesn't ALTER tables (for this reason tools like South are used), but I can try anyway.

This was the output:

./manage.py syncdb
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)

Comment: @AndreaGrandi are you try type the url chaining in your urls.py ?`url(r'^chaining/', include('smart_selects.urls')), `  https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects#installation

Answer (score 0):

If you are editing the profile, you can write a filter for the clients field with "formfield_for_manytomany" https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_manytomany or "formfield_for_choice_field".

But for creating a profile it's only possible to change the client list with javascript afaik. Which can be a tricky thing on the admin forms.

Why do you not just select the clients and omit the formfield for the agency? You could validate the selection afterwards with a validator.

Comment: Also another friend of mine suggested me that this was only possible using clientside javascript (ajax), but... it looks so strange for me. I mean, this is a very common task and it's very strange that this feature is not integrated in django itself.